# How can I get my Rails 3.1 app on a server for testing?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am making a game for Android and using Rails for server coding, and I was wondering how I could get a Rails 3.1 or 3.2 app running somewhere that an android device would have access to from anywhere.  I'd like to test the interactions between the two and I am new to any kind of server/web development.

I understand their is localhost, but I am unsure if an Android device can access this.

Being specific as possible would be excellent, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku would be the easiest solution.

http://www.heroku.com/

edit: Since you need filesystem access you'll need to run the app on your own server. Linode is a pretty good choice.

http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/ubuntu-10.10-maverick

http://help.github.com/deploy-with-capistrano/

Comment: The problem I ran into with Heroku is that it doesn't allow me to write information to the server directly, unless there is a easy way around this?

Comment: What kind of info are you trying to write to the filesystem?

Comment: Well, a user's character in the game may need to update his equipped items, his location (it is geolocation based), or may get hit or heal and need to health or experience when killing enemies, etc.  

This information is first registered by the device then sent to the server in another thread for updating.  If the update fails it will roll back the changes to the client.  I hope that makes sense heh

Comment: You'll probably have to pay for your own server then. You can get a 512MB Linode for $20/month; I've updated my answer with some links.

Comment: Great.  Do you know if there is anyway to connect to my localhost:3000 from my android device?

Comment: You can do it pretty easily through your wireless network. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275218/basic-networking-browsing-to-rails-site-running-on-another-machine